# Dynamically instantiate objects with dependencies in PHP

Tags: php, class, oop

I've created an object factory where I pass the object name as the first parameter and then an array of dependencies as the second parameter. I already have it working but but I feel there has to be a simple php function to allow for the dynamic instantiation of the object.

```
$shinyObject = ObjectFactory::get('Model\MyObject', array('\lib\DependencyOne', '\lib\DependencyTwo'))
```

The purpose of this factory is to retrieve an object thats serialized in session if it exists, if not then create a new instance of the object and then save in session.  I want to know if there is a php function to instantiate a new object dynamically with dependencies.

Comment: I don't think there's any easier way to do this.  What you have looks pretty elegant to me.

Comment: I think you should have a look at `spl_autoload_register` [in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Comment: using Reflection Class API of PHP would probably help you to inject the dependency on your class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, what you're looking after is a dependency injection framework.

PHP doesn't offer such thing out of the box.

There are, however, nice external libraries such as [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/) that provide this kind of functionality. Since you already created such library yourself, I don't think you're going to need it, but I think it was worth mentioning anyway - you can look at how some things are done (for instance, how to deal with singletons, etc.).

The nice thing about PHP-DI is that objects themselves specify what they need, and main object factory takes care of everything, by constructing a map of dependencies (perhaps that is what you meant by "easier" approach - you don't actually need to pass list of dependent objects in PHP-DI).

If I were to make such thing myself, I'd implement `ObjectFactory::define($key, array $deps)` that would be called once per object, and then use just `ObjectFactory::get($key)` whenever I need, without having to know anything about `$$key`'s dependencies.

Answer (score -2):

Just use `new` keyword:

```
$foo = 'Bar'
$bar = new $foo;
```

or you can generate a string and use [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

**Edit**

In response to Justin Kiang's concerns, here is an example:

```
class A
{
}

class Foo
{
    public $a;
    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}

function create($class, array $dependencies)
{
    $str = "\$bar = new $class("; 
    foreach ($dependencies as $dependency)
    {
        $str .= "unserialize('" . serialize($dependency) . "'), ";
    }
    $str = trim($str);
    $str = trim($str, ",") . ");";
    eval($str);
    return $bar;
}

$a = new A;

var_dump(create('Foo', [$a]));
```

It results as follows:

```
object(Foo)[2]
  public 'a' => 
    object(A)[3]
```

Comment: What you provided is probably what the OP has within his get() method.  That's a pretty standard way of coding a factory in that particular design pattern.

Comment: Moreover, what you had is does not take care of dependency injection that the poster had in his factory.

Comment: @justinKiang Take note of the eval function. it does what he wants. with eval you can run a dynamically generated string of php script inside a php script.

Comment: The OP asked if there's a built in php function that injects dependencies, if class Bar needs class DependencyOne and DependencyTwo instantiated and passed in, how can you do that with your eval?  You didn't address that.  Also, he said that he has code working correctly already, don't you think he already is doing what you showed here using the `new` and returning the resulting object?

Comment: @JustinKiang I left the rest to the OP's imagination but here's an edit for you. Now if you intend to just use `new` for dependencies too, you won't be needing any (un)serialization, instead use `new` to make dependencies too. Please care with down-voting.